# Toshiba laptop won't boot. Won't display logo

Tags: boot

I am having problems with our Tohiba laptop. It won't start up. We can't even see the Toshiba logo screen where I can go to BIOS setting. Any help for this?

Comment: Are there any signs of laptop turning on at all? Like LED, noise of fan, hard drive sound, any change of brightness of the display?

Comment: Hi @Nikolay. Screen lights up but it only displays a black screen. Hard drive is running, I can hear it.

Comment: If you have external monitor available -> try to connect it to laptop and see if anything shows up on external monitor.